# why this pattern replacement is not working on array?

Tags: bash, array

for a variable z

```
z="I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX X XI XII XIII XIV XV XVI XVII XVIII XIX XX"
echo "${z// /,}"
```

output is `I,II,III,IV,V,VI,VII,VIII,IX,X,XI,XII,XIII,XIV,XV,XVI,XVII,XVIII,XIX,XX`OK.

but for

```
Y=(I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX X XI XII XIII XIV XV XVI XVII XVIII XIX XX)

echo "${Y[@]// /,}"
```

output is `I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX X XI XII XIII XIV XV XVI XVII XVIII XIX XX`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because for

```
Y=(I II III IV)
```

if you do:

```
"${Y[@]// /,}"
```

All spaces from each element of the array will re replaced by `,`.

For example:

```
$ Y=('I foo' 'II bar' III IV)

$ echo "${Y[@]// /,}"
I,foo II,bar III IV
```

As you have no spaces in any of the elements of the array, nothing is to be replaced.

Comment: thanks, i was trying to put commas between the array elements there is already an answer for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527049/bash-join-elements-of-an-array)